# about official recommendations for protein intake

Tags: nutrition, proteins

The recommendations for protein intake is about 0.8 - 0.9 g/kg/day for a person with moderate activity.
Does one should stick to that quite closely, or would it be prejudicial for health to have just half or two thirds of this intake ? If it is so, what would be the kind of consequences that one should expect in a long run ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about diet and nutrition are off topic here unless directly related to medical treatments.

Comment: Isn't it a bit abusive to close this question ? It IS about medical sciences obviously ! And where is it specified that questions about nutrition are to be related to medical treatments ?

Comment: No, it's not abusive to close questions that that are specifically listed as being off topic here. You might want to visit the [help], and in particular read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where you will find that "questions about nutrition and diet that aren't directly connected to medical treatment" are off topic here.

Comment: Ok you're right, I didn't saw that point, my fault..

Comment: 2 months ago, a question taged in "nutrition"  asked : "Meaning of “natural” in “high natural protein intake” in a consensus guideline on BH4 deficiencies". This question was not related to medical treatments, but was not closed. What does it mean ?

Comment: Read it again. It _was_ about medical treatment as stated in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: OK, so it's off-topic according to the Medicalsciences.SE rules.  In that case, I thought I'd ask, would anyone from here like to take a look at it where it's been re-posted on Vegetarianism.SE?  https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/protein-intake  There's been one answer there but it's, well, pretty short on facts or evidence.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it, it would be nice indeed if someone could give a better answer.